# Is $\overline{D}\subseteq D\circ D$ in a uniform space?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{D})$ is a uniform space and $D\in\mathcal{D}$. Is it true that 
$$\overline{D}\subseteq D\circ D,$$?

here we use the product topology to define $\overline{D}$.

Comment: If $D\subset X\times X$, then $\overline{D}=\bigcap\{U\circ D\circ U: U\in\mathcal{D}\}$. hence $\overline{D}\subset D\circ D\circ D$. I'm not sure but i guess $\overline{D}\subset D\circ D$ is not true.

Comment: @M.Sina: Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: not yet. i think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think this is a counterexample:

Let $\mathcal D$ be the normal uniformity on $\Bbb R$ made by the Euclidean  metric $d$. Let

$$D=U_d(1)\cup \Bbb Q^2$$
where
$$U_d(1)=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \mid d(x,y)\le 1 \}$$

Then
$$(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)\in \overline D$$
But
$$(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)\notin D\circ D$$

Comment: Why are you not sure?